# Installing perl DBD:Pg on Mac

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbd-pg

I run:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::DBD::Pg'
```

it asks:

```
Path to pg_config?
```

I say:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

it runs... and the last lines are:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02attribs.t     (Wstat: 256 Tests: 249 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  23
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=15, Tests=1691, 29 wallclock secs ( 0.23 usr  0.05 sys +  5.29 cusr  1.65 csys =  7.22 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/15 test programs. 1/1691 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-2.19.3.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-2.19.3.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

I saw a DBI_USER config turn to jgp (my login) which i also created in the DB.

Any hint on where I should start?

As requested, here is the full test result:

```
Running make test
PGINITDB="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/initdb" PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-   MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_signature.t .... skipped: Set the environment variable TEST_SIGNATURE to enable this test
t/00basic.t ......... ok   
t/01connect.t ....... Please wait, creating new database for testing
t/01connect.t ....... 1/15 # 
# DBI                         Version 1.631
# DBD::Pg                     Version 2.19.3
# Perl                        Version 5.16.2
# OS                          darwin
# PostgreSQL (compiled)       90302
# PostgreSQL (target)         90302
# PostgreSQL (reported)       PostgreSQL 9.3.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin, compiled by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00), 64-bit
# Default port                5432
# DBI_DSN                     dbi:Pg:db="postgres";port=5440;host=<pwd>/dbdpg_test_database/data/socket
# DBI_USER                    jgp
# Test schema                 dbd_pg_testschema
# LANG                        C
# array_nulls                 on
# backslash_quote             safe_encoding
# client_encoding             UTF8
# server_encoding             UTF8
# standard_conforming_strings on
# Adjusted:                   initdb
t/01connect.t ....... ok     
t/01constants.t ..... ok       
t/02attribs.t ....... 1/249 
#   Failed test 'DB handle attribute "PrintWarn" shows warnings when on'
#   at t/02attribs.t line 263.
#                   ''
#     doesn't match '(?^:dbd_pg_test_temp)'
    (in cleanup) DBD::Pg::st DESTROY failed: no connection to the server at t/02attribs.t line 1558.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 249.
t/02attribs.t ....... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/249 subtests 
t/03dbmethod.t ...... ok       
t/03smethod.t ....... ok     
t/04misc.t .......... 1/70 # Checking pg_st_split_statement. This may take a while...
t/04misc.t .......... ok     
t/06bytea.t ......... ok     
t/07copy.t .......... ok     
t/08async.t ......... ok     
t/09arrays.t ........ ok       
t/12placeholders.t .. ok       
t/20savepoints.t .... ok   
t/99cleanup.t ....... 1/1 Removing test database directory
t/99cleanup.t ....... ok
```

I must admit I am new to perl and PostgreSQL.

Comment: What is the output of the failed test? (not the test summary)

Comment: just edited my post with the full test result - tx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [this has been fixed](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=88865) but not yet included in a new release. Apparently, "Postgres got less chatty in 9.3."

There's a developer release available on CPAN (v2.20.1_6). To install:

```
cpan TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-2.20.1_6.tar.gz
```

or you could pull the latest source with `git`.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, I only had to answer the pg_config question, to which my answer was:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_config

Comment: As you saying other answer resolves the problem. This is really a comment. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).